# Suppose that A ⊂ Z , and inf(A) exists. Show that min(A) exists, and min(A) = inf(A)

Tags: real-analysis

Let a = inf(A)

If a exists, a has a lower bound and for all lower bounds a', we have a' ≤ a.

If a is a minimum then, a is a lower bound and a ∈ A.

As A is a subset of integers, a is a whole number. So for any set A in Z, inf(A) = min(A).

This is the logic i could come up with. Any help on how to prove that is much appreciated thanks.

Comment: Are there any additional qualifications on A? Because $A = \{ \mathbb{Z} \cap (-\infty,0) \} \subset \mathbb{Z}$ doesn't have a minimum, its infimum would be $-\infty$. Also, any $a \in A$ as I defined it in this example would not be a whole number, so that line in your logic doesn't make sense.

Comment: The existence of inf$(A)$ does not imply that min$(A) =$ inf$(A)$. An example of this is the set $A=(0,1)$. Clearly, inf$(A) = 0$ but min$(A) \neq 0$. min$(A) \neq$ inf$(A)$ because inf$(A) = 0$ but $0 \not\in (0,1) = A$.

Comment: You need to show that if the set of integers $A$ has an infinum in the reals   then that infimum is an integer and belongs to $A$. Ignore the above comments which mistakenly assume either that you are working in the extended real number line or that $A$ is not a set of integers.